# Problem with span tags inside select tags

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have the following HTML:

```js
const span = document.getElementById("userdropdownlist");
console.log(span);
```

```html
<select>
<span id="userdropdownlist"></span><br>
</select>
```

When I try to use `document.getElementById` with the above `span` ID, I get the error message

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null".

It seems to me that javascript can't see `span` IDs inside `select` tags.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: That is invalid HTML so not a surprise it causes issues

Comment: "How can I get around this problem?" — By writing actual HTML: https://validator.nu/

Comment: What is the purpose of adding <span> inside select? Could you please add your code snippet that you used to capture element.

Answer (score 2):

selects can't contain `<span>` elements the only thing select can contain is `<option>`

Comment: How can I dynamically change the options in a dropdown menu?

Comment: @tim.tub — By appending and removing options. Why would a span be involved?

Comment: by changing it's dom structure

Comment: I am wanting to be able to use javascript  to change the dropdown options once the page has loaded without reloading the page.

Comment: @tim.tub And why would you need a `<span>` element for this? Just modify the `<select>` itself ([`.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild), [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), ...)

Comment: Thank you Andreas. Yours has been the most useful answer. I am very much a newbie about this. I did not know about removeChild(), appendchild() etc. Now I do.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned it's invalid HTML to place anything but an `<option>` as a child of a `<select>`. The following demo features function `options()`. It's purpose is to add options to a given select according to a given Map object. The Map object stores the value and text content for each option.

Details are commented in demo.

```js
/*[REQUIRED]
Prepare a Map Object as the first parameter
Each sub-array is an option [value, text]
These key/value pairs/sub-arrays are nested within another array 
then passed to the Map()
*/
let kvp = new Map([
  ['Alpha', 'α'],
  ['Beta', 'β'],
  ['Gamma', 'γ'],
  ['Delta', 'δ'],
  ['Epsilon', 'ε'],
  ['Zeta', 'ζ']
]);

/*[REQUIRED]
First param is the Map previously mentioned
Second param is a selector string of the select receiving options
-A- Reference the select
-B- Iterate thru the map -- destructure the key/value to access
-C- Create an option
-D- Get val from map and set it to option value
-E- Get txt from map and set it to option text
-F- Add to select
*/
const options = (map, select) => {
  const sel = document.querySelector(select); //A
  for (let [val, txt] of map) { //B
    let opt = document.createElement('option'); //C
    opt.value = val; //D
    opt.text = txt; //E
    sel.add(opt); //F
  }
}

// Call options() pass kvp Map and selector String
options(kvp, '.sel');

/* [OPTIONAL] 
When change event happens on select.sel output.out displays select.sel value
*/
document.querySelector('.sel').onchange = function(e) {
  document.querySelector('.out').value = this.value;
}
```

```css
select,
output {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 700 64px/1.2 Consolas
}
```

```html
<select class='sel'></select>
<output class='out'></output>
```